# Place commas in Javascript integers

Tags: javascript, localization

So I have a value in Javascript:

```
var val = Entry.val;
```

One example of this value is `277385`. How do I, in Javascript, convert this number to `277,385`, as well as any number to that so it has commas in the correct spots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it for you:

**Function:**

```
  function addCommas(nStr)
    {
        nStr += '';
        x = nStr.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
        }
        return x1 + x2;
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
addCommas(1000)
// 1,000

addCommas(1231.897243)
// 1,231.897243
```

Thanks to [mredjk.com](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html)

Comment: You beat me to the exact same function. That was the first answer that came up in Google.

Comment: I like how you post the same code as Prisoner, but the difference is that he provides a link to the place whence you both got it.

Answer (score 9):

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

via [here](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html).

Comment: +1 to you for adding the link back to the source (even though it's of public domain). ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
val.replace(/(\d{1,3})(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/g,"$1,")
```

:-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the other answers split the number on a decimal point-
you can replace, starting with a digit,until there are no more digits.
It will quit when it runs out of digits or hits a non-digit.

```
function addCommas(n){
    var rx= /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    return String(n).replace(/^\d+/, function(w){
        while(rx.test(w)) w= w.replace(rx,'$1,$2');
        return w;
    });
}
```