# Putting commas in a number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Place commas in Javascript integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820482/place-commas-in-javascript-integers)

I have a variable containing a number in JavaScript and I want to display it with commas in all the right places.  So, for 222222 I need 222,222 and for 1000333 I need 1,000,333.  What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function addGrouping(val, grouper) {
    val += '';
    x = val.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + grouper + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}

addGrouping(1231.897243, ",")
// 1,231.897243
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xn44C/)

Comment: Was this copied from here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820482/place-commas-in-javascript-integers Same value being tested with..

Comment: I have a program which contains snippets of code I've collected. It may have come from there originally - but I didn't copy it directly!

Comment: Ah okay, I've marked this question as a duplicate anyway as its exactly the same

Comment: Sorry - I never think to check for dupes.

Comment: I've just come across this: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html. It seems the function is more generic than I thought, apologies for questioning you as a copy-cat :P

Comment: No problem...... blah blah limit etc.